# javascript - array reference is not cleared

Tags: javascript

When I assign anotherArrayList = arrayList, anotherArrayList is a pointer to arrayList. So why this does not work when I empty the arrayList.

```
var arrayList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']; 
var anotherArrayList = arrayList;  

arrayList[1] = '15';

console.log(arrayList); // output: [ "a", "15", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
console.log(anotherArrayList); // output: [ "a", "15", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]

arrayList = []; 
console.log(arrayList); // output: []
console.log(anotherArrayList); // output: [ "a", "15", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
```

Comment: When you do `arrayList = [];` you aren't changing the object that `arrayList` was pointing at; you're making `arrayList` point at a new object. Your premise is wrong: "I empty the arrayList" is not what's happening.

Comment: @ChrisG This should be an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have 2 variables pointing to the same object? (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143799/is-it-possible-to-have-2-variables-pointing-to-the-same-object-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there pointers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382427) and [js replace object / change reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814414)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass-by-reference JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290747/pass-by-reference-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assigning a new array, the old object reference gets a new reference to the empty array.

You could assign zero to the `length` property which empties the object reference as well.

```js
var arrayList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    anotherArrayList = arrayList;

arrayList[1] = '15';

console.log(arrayList);        // [ "a", "15", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
console.log(anotherArrayList); // [ "a", "15", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]

arrayList.length = 0; 
console.log(arrayList);        // []
console.log(anotherArrayList); // []
```

Comment: This doesn't answer he question.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't empty your other array because you're not actually clearing/emptying it, instead you are creating a *new* empty array in memory, which `arrayList` will point to, whereas `anotherArrayList` will still point to the full array.

Instead, to empty the array itself, you can use the `.length` property: `arrayList.length = 0`

```js
var arrayList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']; 
var anotherArrayList = arrayList;  

arrayList[1] = '15';

console.log(arrayList); // output: [ "a", "15", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
console.log(anotherArrayList); // output: [ "a", "15", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]

arrayList.length = 0; 
console.log(arrayList); // output: []
console.log(anotherArrayList); // output: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Array and objects are **non-primitive** data-type in javascript. When a variable is assigned with reference to a non-primitive data-type, the copy of memory location is stored in that new variable.